# How to Attach files with sending mail in android application?

Tags: android, email

I am sending mail through my application.
For that I am using following code.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

It just work fine but i want to attach an xml file with it.
Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of similar questions asked with perfect solution in Stack Overflow already.

You can have look to few : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587917/trying-to-attach-a-file-from-sd-card-to-email) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834567/android-possible-to-attach-a-file-to-email-without-writing-to-sd) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264622/android-multiple-email-attachments-using-intent)

Solution is to use with email intent : one more **putExtra with Key-Extra_Stream and Value-uri to file**.

And please go through the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to undersatand How to better benifit from the site.

Answer (score 3):

```
String pathname= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String filename="/MyFiles/mysdfile.txt";
File file=new File(pathname, filename);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Content");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
i.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Your email id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` should be the action and then `emailIntent.setType("text/plain");` followed by:

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
String[] filePaths = new String[] {"sdcard/sample.png", "sdcard/sample.png"};
for (String file : filePaths)
{
    File fileIn = new File(file);
    Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
    uris.add(u);
}
emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

For sending an attachment with gmail:

1. File should be on External storage device or created in External storage device

   - For that you need to add the following to Android Manifest
     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
   - get External path by

     `String pathname= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();`
   - Create a new file by

     `File myfile=new File(pathname,filename);`
   - Write to file based on whatever logic you are applying
   - Now the Intent

     `Intent email=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);`

     `email.setType("plain/text");`
   - Put Extras

     `email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(myfile));`                                    `email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "my email subject");`
                                         `email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "my email text");`
   - Start Activity
                                         `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "E-mail"));`