# How to send attached file using intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using below code to send email to gmail.Here , i am directly open compose mail of the gmail.it's worked fine.but i need to attache file to that mail.How can i do ? 
Please can any one help me?

Here my code is:

```
Intent send = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            String uriText = "mailto:" + Uri.encode("user@gmail.com") + 
                      "?subject=" + Uri.encode("Testing app") + 
                      "&body=" + Uri.encode("Hi,this is android app testing");
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);

            send.setData(uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(send, "Send mail..."));
```

Thanking in Advance.

Comment: you can search on stackoverlow itself. there are lots of similar posts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466169/how-to-attach-files-with-sending-mail-in-android-application

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
Uri.fromFile(file);
send.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

EDIT try this one then:

```
intent.setType("application/zip"); //if it's a zip otherwise whatever you file formap is.
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + zipDestinationString));
```

if you wish to use gmail you need to specific the exact intent you want to use:

```
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");

//note one might generate an exception so you should catch the exception and try the other.


intent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivity");
```

Here is also a CodeProject sample app that does that:
[Code Project Send Mail With Attachment Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/268122/Send-email-with-attachment-by-android)

Comment: file attachement worked with bellow code . but it's open gmail,email,Skype etc.. but i need directly compose mail .    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        email.setType("message/rfc822");
        
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "suman.chidurala546@gmail.com" });
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Resume");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Please find attachment");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(myFile));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email , "Email: Text File"));

Comment: I do not understand, what is the problem then? Try to revise your question better.

Comment: I am sending attached file using above code.But , when click on send button it will open all installed mailing app like gmail,yahoo,Skype etc...but i want directly open the gmail.i don't need all unnecessary apps.But i am using first posted code it directly opens the gmail but i unable to attach the files.

Comment: oh, let me revise the answer then..it was not clear from your quesiton..

Comment: by using intent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail"); this code it's worked fine in android version 4.1.1 but in 2.2 i didn't see any attached file in compose mail.

Comment: ok, so you should try the second option. please note you will have to choose between the two options as one might not work, or raise an exception..