# Attach json File to eMail Intent in Android

Tags: android, json, android-intent

how can I attach a JSONObject as a json File to a eMail Intent in Android?

My code for this is at the moment:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("text");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "blabla");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "blabla");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "blabla");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

Comment: 1. Create .txt file from your json Object 2. [Attach .txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19254607/2591002)

Comment: first create json file and save in sdcard than attached with email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("text");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "blabla");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "blabla");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "blabla");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/file.json"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```