# I just want to browse the file and it as file in my e-mail How should I attach:

Tags: java, email-attachments

```
if (attachFiles != null && attachFiles.length > 0) {
        for (String filePath : attachFiles) {
            MimeBodyPart attachPart = new Mienter code heremeBodyPart();

            try {
                attachPart.attachFile(filePath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
        }
    }
```

I just want to browse the file and send this file in my e-mail using java email

How should I attach,Here is code for attatch file in java with hard coded location but i want to add browse file in my email.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance @@

Comment: Where is your code where your browser/ask for the file(s) to attach? What's wrong/not working with it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466169/how-to-attach-files-with-sending-mail-in-android-application