# how to attach a file for email in worklight using cordova

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Im using worklight 6.0.

I have to send email with attachment as a file in jquery.
I read in many sites like we can use email composer .
How to implement this one or any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the cardova plugin which is well documented and plugin is there for doing it. Here is some of the link which helps you

[Cardova plugin for Email Composer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer)

[There is a sample code for IOS](https://github.com/steve-jansen/cordova-ios-emailcomposer)

Comment: @user2967626 , if you found this as answer and solves your problem. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has got nothing to do with it.

- If you would like to open the email client from your app you can use a URL scheme: `window.location.href = "mailto:an@email.address?subject=My Subject Line";`
- If you would like to also attach a file, I believe you will need to [write a Cordova plug-in](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova) for this purpose, and as for the contents (code) of the plug-in itself, you may want to take a look at these questions ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834567/android-possible-to-attach-a-file-to-email-without-writing-to-sd), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264622/android-multiple-email-attachments-using-intent)).